# How do I change just one dimension in Preview, when dragging/using the mouse?

Tags: preview

In Preview, I want to change just the width of an image by dragging the points/dots surrounding the image on the sides, with my mouse.  But instead of just the width changing, the entire image gets changed, both height and width.  This started happening when I upgraded to Mavericks.  How can I control the dragging feature in Previews again?  Being able to adjust just the width or just the height separately?  Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by changing the width of an image? Are you talking about resizing images or selection boxes? Usually, you simply hold the Shift key while dragging for this kind of thing. For an edge point, this will ensure that only one dimension is changed. For corner points, the box will scale proportionally in both dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

in Preview with the picture open:
when it fills the window completely, click on it with CMD - (command plus the minus sign).
this will give you manipulation space.
then place the mouse pointer inside the picture, a + sign appears, drag this to where you want to start, a blue drag line appears, place it around the picture completely; then when you want to the picture smaller drag that side, and click Tools->Crop in the menubar of Preview.